# jQuery slideDown changes width by 1px

Tags: jquery

I spent couple of days already, I have no ideas any more, how to fix my problem.
I'll show with screenshots :

[image] 
[image]
Idea of this is, that when mouse is not on element, it shows only top and bottom part, when mouseover, middle element slides down.
As you can see, in first image, middle part (where is facebook and google+ icons), that background is repeated pattern, it is 1px thiner, than in image on right. Same element captured on different screen resolutions. Our content scales with screen resolution. It is strange, that all images are with same widths, but looks different.

css code:

```
.ribbon .vintage .nolog {
width: 92px;
}

.ribbon .vintage .nolog .top {
width: 92px;
height: 59px;
background: url("/img/ribbon/vintage/n/vintage_nolog_top.png");
}
.ribbon .vintage .nolog .center {
width: 92px;
display: none;
background: url("/img/ribbon/vintage/n/vintage_nolog_repeat.png") repeat-y;
}
.ribbon .vintage .nolog .bottom {
width: 92px;
height: 69px;   
background: url("/img/ribbon/vintage/n/vintage_nolog_bottom.png");
}
```

html i am generating through jquery :

```
(....).append($('<div/>', {'class': 'vintage'}).hover(slideDown, slideUp).(....)
//and here those animating functions
    var slideUp = function() {
        $(this).find('.center').stop(true, false).slideUp(options.duration);
    }
    var slideDown = function() {
        $(this).find('.center').stop(true, true).slideDown(options.duration);
    }
```

Code is pretty simple.. Oh, this error apears only on Chrome :x

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QbX9f/
There is some mouseover glitches, but i dont have them in real application. Also - result is as i expected - here you cannot see the glitch, it is caused by css3 scale(), that is applied to all elements.. But the strangest thing - only on chrome.

UPDATE :/
I found now, that when i dont repeat middle part ( set its height to background image height), it does'nt shrink! So strange.

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QbX9f/
But it was pretty difficult to grab it out of my application, but you can see the main thing.